# Como convertir de string a varbinary?

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, mvc, conversión-de-tipos

Estoy trabajando en el lenguaje c# y quisiera saber cómo convertir un dato string a varbinary ya que estoy realizando una consulta a una base de datos (SQL Server) y me devuelve los datos en string y uno de esos datos necesito asignarlo a una variable que está en varbinary. Los datos los traigo mediante un Datarow para igual si saben otra forma de traer datos de una base de datos con sus datos de origen y que no me los devuelva en string. Igual use esta conversión pero no me devuelve lo que yo quiero  “ usuario.foto = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(row["foto"].ToString());” donde “usuario.foto” es mi variable varbinary y mi row[“foto”] la variable string, dejo el código para que vean

```
    public usuarioBO obtenerperfil()
    {
        ConexionDAO conexion = new ConexionDAO();
        var usuario = new usuarioBO();
        string strbuscar = string.Format("select * from Usuario where ID='1006';");
        DataTable dats = conexion.ejercutarsentrenciasdatable(strbuscar);
        DataRow row = dats.Rows[0];
        usuario.correo = row["Correo"].ToString();
        usuario.nombre = row["Nombre"].ToString();
        usuario.apellido = row["Apellido"].ToString();
        usuario.sexo = row["sexo"].ToString();
        usuario.correo = row["Correo"].ToString();
        usuario.telefono = row["Telefono"].ToString();
        usuario.fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Fecha"].ToString());
        usuario.foto = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(row["foto"].ToString());


        return usuario;
    }
```

Comment: No sera que la variable `usuario.foto` es string `row["foto"]` es varbinary?

Comment: Que tipo de dato es la propiedad `usuario.foto`?

Comment: es la tengo declarada como `public byte[] foto { get; set; }`, pero ahora que lo veo es byte

Comment: tendria algo que ver?

Comment: cuando pongo ToByte me dice que No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo Byte en Byte[]

Comment: Puedes mostrar como guardas los datos en esa tabla? Porque todo depende del enconding que utilizas para guadar los datos.

Comment: En la base de datos lo tengo puesto como varbinary(MAX) y lo que busco es guardar una imagen, ya lo logre solo me falta devolver esa imagen la forma en como la guarda es esta "0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D494844" como ejemplo porque el dato si es muy grande

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`varbinary` es un `byte[]` asi que solo tendrias que convertir el resultado a byte[] para obtener los bytes de la columna asi:

```
usuario.foto = (byte[])row["foto"];
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano :D me has salvado ya me devulve la imagen, te lo agradezco como mucho, me llevo todo el dia hacer eso, muchas gracias c;

Comment: Fue un placer ayudarte :D